# EmbeddedObjectPart to Image using C#

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, openxml

There is a a MS-Paint file in the my docx. I want to extract the MS-Paint file as a Image (any format as JPEG, PNG, GIF) from docx by conversion process in my C# application.

I couldn't find any API references that the EmbeddedObjectPart Bin export interface is provided by OOXML. How to extract MS-Paint file as a Image from docx?

Comment: maybe this could help you? http://forums.asp.net/t/1474743.aspx

Comment: Thanks FatGiant, Word document can insert two kind of Image. 1. ImagePart, and 2. EmbeddedObjectPart.  I done the 1st type and the url also 1st type, I am asking 2nd type.